# How can I use Diskpart to merge System Reserve and the Windows partition before installing Windows?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, merge, diskpart

Disk 0 contains three partitions: 1, 2, and 3.
1, 2, and 3 are System Reserve, the Windows partition, and the data partition respectively.

```
DISKPART 
Select Disk 0
Select partition 1   
Delete partition
Select partition 2
Delete partition
Create partition primary
```

Partition 1 and 2 will merge into a single primary partition, where Windows can be installed. 
Am I right?

Comment: Windows installations are getting more and more prolific in the number of partitions they use, so you won't get a single partition afterwards. If there's nothing else on the disc, simply format the whole drive and allow Windows to create the partitions it wants during the installation. If you have another OS on the disc, then you can delete the partitions you specify, but don't create a new one: let the installer do this. You probably won't be able to boot the other OS without running a boot manager, either in the new Windows or from an external recovery disc for the old OS.

Comment: I know Windows setup will create more than one partition afterward, but I just want to know whether my commands are correct. I won't delete the data partition. No other OSes are on the disk.

Comment: If you fill the free space with a single partition, then there will be no space for the other partitions Windows needs. The other commands look right, but I'm not prepared to try them!

Comment: @MatthewWai - It might help to understand what pratical problem your attempting to solve by running the commands you provided.

Comment: There is no practical problem. I just want to know whether it is possible to merge two partitions via Diskpart.